# Voip notifications in ios 13 whatsapp working

Tags: swift, whatsapp

As we knew from ios 13 we can use voip notification in association with call kit. You can not only use voip notifications without call kit.
Does anyone have idea how whatsapp is still using voip notification services in ios 13 without call kit..

Comment: Did you get any solution for this. I mean how you achieved this?

Comment: They have privilege https://stackoverflow.com/a/61011477/1289480