# iOS 13 Voip notification retry

Tags: ios, voip, ios13

For better handling, our server has logic of retry notifications when the expected response from the client is not received. Now for IOS 13 all voip notifications are in association with callkit, it is mandating duplicate call indications to callkit.

Is there any possibility to handle these duplicate notifications(caused due to retries) without invoking callkit.

Comment: Follow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61011477/8956604)

Comment: What you should do is indicate an incoming call when you get the first push.  If you get another push while you are already indicating an incoming call it is ok to ignore it as you are already indicating a call

Comment: As per the documentation[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry], On iOS 13.0 and later, if you fail to report a call to CallKit, the system will terminate your app. Repeatedly failing to report calls may cause the system to stop delivering any more VoIP push notifications to your app. If you want to initiate a VoIP call without using CallKit,
Here I am worried about IOS 13 behavior, as IOS terminate the app if the second push i.e duplicate is ignored in app