# Provisioning profile doesn't include the com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-VOIP entitlement

Tags: ios, voip, provisioning-profile, entitlements, pushkit

In XCode project, I have added entitlements file. Now if i am adding any value inside that file like.

com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-voip Bool Yes.

It gives error while running.
Provisioning profile "Development" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-VOIP entitlement.

How can I add value in the Provisioning profile for entitlements entry?

Comment: Go to your Apple developer account and select your provisioning profile and download it after adding push kit by check mark it

Comment: Did that but still show error

Comment: I don't believe you can add that entitlement yourself. Apple needs to grant it to you

Comment: We can add it but need to add it in profile

Comment: That is what I mean. You can add it to the entitlements file, but only Apple can add it to your profile. They will only do this if you apply and provide a good reason why you need it. I imagine it was granted to WhatsApp because the iOS 13 change would have affected millions of users and they need time to update their code. Unless you have millions of users I don't think you can get this entitlement.

Comment: Thanks For sharing information.  is com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-voip part of the push notification(Capability) option. I turn it on my bundle identifier. it should work? from your message it's look like there is no way to do or we need to connect apple to allow us to add it.

Comment: Voip push notifications are enabled by the "VoIP" capability. To use voip push enable VoIP and push notification capabilities. The unrestricted push entitlement allows the pre-ios13 behaviour where your app doesn't need to indicate an incoming call when it receives a VoIP push.  This can only be granted by Apple.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62770908/1072411

Comment: Thanks for sharing. got your point.

Comment: why is there a bounty? the question was solved.. no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consult with apple developer support for same and they share

"My apologies but at this point in time, we don’t have any additional information about the unrestricted entitlement that you are asking about. All available information on the current entitlements is linked [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements)."

For more details Please review bellow Threds

1. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117939
2. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118607

Hope this will help to others.

Answer (score 4):

While you can add this entitlement to your entitlements file, it is not an entitlement you can add to the profile yourself. Only Apple can grant this entitlement and they have not provided any public information on a process to request this entitlement.

I suspect that this entitlement was only granted to high-profile apps, such as WhatsApp, that needed time to adapt to the new VoIP push behaviour that was introduced in iOS 13.